# Is the Observer Pattern applicable when Subject and Observer need to be in separate assemblies?

Tags: c#, observer-pattern

I have seen multiple examples of the Observer pattern with the Subject and Observer in the same assembly.  It seems to me that a more 'real world' example would have the Subject and Observer(s) in separate assemblies on different machines communicating across a network or the internet.  Is the Observer Pattern applicable in this situation or is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have subjects and observers it's the Observer pattern. What does being in separate assemblies have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

"Separate assemblies" is an implementation detail.  Implementation details do not matter when deciding whether a pattern applies.

You can absolutely apply the Observer Pattern across assembly boundaries, or across physical boundaries.

You can consider the [publish/subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern or the [mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern as alternatives.